# Android studio gradle script can't find Pattern class

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I'm trying to add an autoincremental version name feature to my gradle script but I'm getting the error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'Pattern' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        def version = getIncrementationVersions()
        versionCode 100
        versionName version
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug
                {
                    minifyEnabled false
                }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            if (outputFile != null && outputFileName.endsWith('.aar')) {
                if (name.equals(com.android.builder.core.BuilderConstants.DEBUG))
                    outputFileName = "lib-debug.aar";
                else
                    outputFileName = "lib-release.aar";

                //outputFileName = "${archivesBaseName}-${version}.aar"
            }
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

def getIncrementationVersions()
{
    List<String> runTasks = gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames();

    //find version name in manifest
    def manifestFile = file('src/main/AndroidManifest.xml')
    def matcher = Pattern.compile('versionName=\"(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\"').matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    matcher.find()

    //extract versionName parts
    def firstPart = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
    def secondPart = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2))

    //check is runTask release or not
    // if release - increment version
    for (String item : runTasks)
    {
        secondPart++
    }

    def versionName = firstPart + "." + secondPart

    // update manifest
    def manifestContent = matcher.replaceAll('versionName=\"' + versionName + '\"')
    manifestFile.write(manifestContent)

    println "incrementVersionName = " + versionName

    return versionName
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation "net.pubnative:advertising_id_client:1.0.1"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

It seems I can use any Groovy class in an android studio gradle script.

What is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your build script, it seems that you don't import the needed class `java.util.regex.Pattern` (or maybe you did not copy/paste the whole script?)

In Groovy and Gradle there are some "default imports" (see [Groovy default imports](http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_default_imports) and [Gradle default imports](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#script-default-imports)) , but  `java.util.regex` package is not part of these, so you have to import the `Pattern`class yourself.

Add this import at top of your `build.gradle` script

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern
```

Or simply use full qualified name

```
def getIncrementationVersions()
{
    // ...

    //find version name in manifest
    def manifestFile = file('src/main/AndroidManifest.xml')
    def matcher = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile('versionName=\"(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\"').matcher(manifestFile.getText())

    // ...
}
```